# How to increase font quality on drawString method of Graphics?

Tags: buffer, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, antialiasing

In Paint XP or Paint Windows 8, when you write text, the program automatically increases the quality of the font (at least for fiscal printers). I would like to know how to do this with the same Java code below.

First, look at this image to see what I mean:

[image: Text Quality Example]

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("blankdocument.bmp"));
Graphics g = ((BufferedImage) image).getGraphics();

Font helvetica = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", Font.PLAIN, 13);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.setFont(helvetica);

g.drawString("TEXT WRITING EXAMPLE.", 5, 10);
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("testx.PNG"));
image.flush();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn on anti-aliasing. From [Controlling Rendering Quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html),

> To set or change the rendering hints attribute in the `Graphics2D` context, construct a [`RenderingHints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) object and pass it into `Graphics2D` by using the `setRenderingHints` method. If you just want to set one hint, you can call `Graphics2D` `setRenderingHint` and specify the key-value pair for the hint you want to set. (The key-value pairs are defined in the `RenderingHints` class.)

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
```

Comment: Thanks, very well Elliott.

Comment: any way to increase it? xD

Comment: I find the atributte "_LCD_HRGB" (replacing: RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB),
good, no more questions, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on [Anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing). Anti-aliasing in java can be enabled like so:

```
// this is the same as getGraphics() but returns a Graphics2D instead.
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
```